# where to find documentation about the special php exec method using back quotes ?

Tags: php, exec, native, trace

I have some sample program that runs a php script that does some exec command by using the syntax:

```
echo "Do invoke native commmand: ";
    `curl "http://localhost/somescript.php`;
```

Those " ` " sign seems to have a similar effect to a regular "exec" command. It just seems to prevent me from reading the proper response.

Now I can't find *any* kind of documentation about the effect of " ` "

How would you call that even ? Is that another syntax for "exec" or where is that command documented in the PHP docs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Backtick operator is identical to [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), **not** [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Meaning that it will return the whole output of the cmd as a string, while `exec()` just returns the last line from output. (but `exec()` has additional params the get the whole output *and* the return value of the command)

Documentation can be found in the PHP manual, [Backtick Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

> PHP supports one execution operator: backticks (``). Note that these are not single-quotes! PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command; the output will be returned (i.e., it won't simply be dumped to output; it can be assigned to a variable). Use of the backtick operator is identical to shell_exec().